# New to Android: Adding More Options on Android Virtual Device

Tags: android

I am relatively new to Android and I just made a HelloWorld Android Application and I just wanted to add more options for my devices when I launch it on my AVD. I only have target: Android 4.4 as my only Option but I see in the tutorials that there are more AVD target options.

Please let me know!

Comment: So you want to create virtual devices for older versions of android, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Launch the SDK Manager and install required packages.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html